# Corrupted image on uploading image to AWS-S3 via signed url

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload images to aws-s3 via a signed-url from NodeJS server (not from a browser). The image to upload has been generated by NodeJS. I'm getting the signed-url from aws and succeeding to upload it to s3.

But my image is corrupted. For some reason, S3 is adding some headers to my image (compare image attached).

What am I doing wrong?

getting the signed url:

```
    try {
        var params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: 'FILE_NAME.png',
            Expires: 60
        };
        const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
        return url;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
```

uploading to s3

```
        var stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
        var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
        const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

        var formData = {
            'file': {
                value: imageBuffer,
                options: {
                    filename: 'FILE_NAME.png'
                }
            }
        };

        request({ 
            method: 'put',
            url, 
            headers: {
                'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes,
                'Content-MD': md5(imageBuffer)           
            }, 
            formData 
        }, function (err, res, body) {
             console.log('body',body);
        });
```

Compare between the actual image and the uploaded image to s3. S3 added some headers:

[image: compare]

Answer (score 36):

I know this is old but I struggled with the same issue for a while. When uploading using a pre-signed url, DO NOT use new FormData();

One thing I noticed that all of my files on s3 were exactly 2kb larger than the originals.

```
<input type="file" id="upload"/>

var upload = document.getElementById('upload');
var file = upload.files[0];

//COMMENTED OUT BECAUSE IT WAS CAUSING THE ISSUE
//const formData = new FormData();
//formData.append("file", file);

// Assuming axios

const config = {
    onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
        );
        console.log(percentCompleted);
    },
    header: {
        'Content-Type': file.type
    }
};

axios.put(S3SignedPutURL, file, config)
   .then(async res => {
        callback({res, key})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: Love you man :D, I don't know why there are lots of tutorials and SO posts and all of them using new FormData(), thanks!!

Comment: Thanks man! that was what I needed. It is strange those extra 2kb

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once. many thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you happen to know how we can upload the file with a different name with this method?

Comment: I could kiss you! The rest of the internet told me to use FormData !

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer as it is likely the correct one in most cases.

Comment: @KashifImran I know I am late but yet you can. I rename the file on the backend when I am calling for s3.getSignedUrl. I'm able to manipulate the key attribute that is passed.

Comment: to those that use fetch (instead of Axios) you can change to "body: file" and it will work (without the form)

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  Solved the problem straight away.

Comment: It helped after updating from header to headers on the config object

Comment: still works in 2023. Thumbs up

Answer (score 6):

Came here in 2023, was facing the same problem using formdata, but in postman, before handing it to the front end department.

To handle it in postman, use the type of request body as `binary`:
[image]

And don't forget to add the proper headers.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the above solution for react js

What I was doing before uploading an image is passing through the createObject URL and then passing it to the API body.

```
if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            let img = e.target.files[0];
            **setImage(URL.createObjectURL(img))**
```

Correct Way:

```
if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            let img = e.target.files[0];
            **setImage(img)**
```

Work For me, Thanks Sam Munroe

Answer (score -1):

Try to specify the content type in the request as `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data`.