Image rendering issue in react web UI
I have an image uploaded on S3 that I want to render in my react website as the profile picture of the logged in user.

The S3 bucket where this image is stored has a following bucket policy. I can also verify that the object has a correct content type of image/jpeg set as System Defined metadata. When I do a get request to fetch the image I get a response code of 200 in my network tab but the image does not renders. Attached is the screenshot of the same. I have also verified that the Object Ownership is of bucket owner enforced hence ACLs being disabled.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow only GET requests originating from www.wecoach.ai and wecoach.ai",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wecoach-user-data/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://wecoach.ai/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Very likely the object WEWELLNESS.jpeg in the S3 bucket is not a jpg image.  How have you verified it is?

I can verify the same by checking the Metadata section on the s3 console for the object. Also when uploading the object via UI, I set the content-type header. Here are the details of the metadata. https://pasteboard.co/U1MshkqNe88W.png

Metadata does not mean the object itself is a valid image.  It just means the metadata is correct.  The object in S3 is very likely broken or incorrect in some way.

Here is the react code for uploading the image https://pastebin.com/jffAp972
Any check i can implement and/or how should I make sure the data is not corrupted?

You could download it from S3 and try to open the file in an image editor or viewer.

I mean I tried that , but I was asking in terms of my code, how do I make sure the image does not change during the upload process

@AnonCoward Thanks man, I figured out it's a JS issue, I should not be using new FormData for this specific use case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234437/corrupted-image-on-uploading-image-to-aws-s3-via-signed-url

The issue is not in the S3 settings but in how I am uploading the image, it turns out that I should not be using
new FormData()

while uploading to a pre-signed URL.
Reference
Corrupted image on uploading image to AWS-S3 via signed url
